# HTML font not properly working on my computer but works on other devices

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-family

Hi i am new to the HTML but i am having this issue where in my pc the font is not working or showing the right font-family but it works on IE or other computer any idea what seems to be the issue? I need to know the Accurate result of my style since i don't have an idea on what my webpage looked like until i presented it on my class

```
        <p style="font-size: 500%;
                    font-family: Fantasy;
                    color: white;">
            10 Important Computer Personalities<br>
            <span style="font-size: 50%;-webkit-text-stroke-width: 2px;">List by: Name</span>
        </p>
```

Here is the result on my Chrome or Microsoft Edge it is showing the Impact Font or what i atleast have expected the result

[What i have expected or showing on my PC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddMGN.png)

And here is the result in other computers/devices or IE

[What i get on other device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ux4pK.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`font-family: fantasy` does not load a specific font, `fantasy` is a [special keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-family#generic-name) (the other four being `serif`, `sans-serif`, `monospace`, and `cursive`) that tells the browser to load "any font that is in the fantasy category". You are *guaranteed* that by using it, different computers may load different fonts. If you want to load a *specific* font, using a webfont is the only real way to ensure all browsers, on all systems, load the same font.